# Symfony 3.3.12 migration from AWS / RDS Maria DB 10.0 fail: DBALException

Tags: symfony, doctrine, dbal

I'm try to migrate a API made with Symfony 3.3.12, installed on AWS using a database with Amazon RDS based on MariaDb MariaDB 10.0.24

On my log get this:

```
[2018-06-23 18:22:52] request.INFO: Matched route "api_login_check". {"route":"api_login_check","route_parameters":{"_route":"api_login_check"},"request_uri":"https://api.excellenting.com/api/login_check","method":"POST"} []
[2018-06-23 18:22:54] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException: "An exception occured while establishing a connection to figure out your platform version. You can circumvent this by setting a 'server_version' configuration value  For further information have a look at: https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineBundle/issues/673" at /home/ubuntu/symfony_backend/vendor/doctrine/doctrine-bundle/ConnectionFactory.php line 96 {"exception":"[object] (Doctrine\\DBAL\\DBALException(code: 0): An exception occured while establishing a connection to figure out your platform version.\nYou can circumvent this by setting a 'server_version' configuration value\n\nFor further information have a look at:\nhttps://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineBundle/issues/673 at /home/ubuntu/symfony_backend/vendor/doctrine/doctrine-bundle/ConnectionFactory.php:96, Doctrine\\DBAL\\Exception\\ConnectionException(code: 0): An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused at /home/ubuntu/symfony_backend/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/AbstractMySQLDriver.php:108, Doctrine\\DBAL\\Driver\\PDOException(code: 2002): SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused at /home/ubuntu/symfony_backend/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php:47, PDOException(code: 2002): SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused at /home/ubuntu/symfony_backend/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php:43)"} []
[2018-06-23 18:53:39] request.ERROR: Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: "No route found for "HEAD /"" at /home/ubuntu/symfony_backend/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/EventListener/RouterListener.php line 123 {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\NotFoundHttpException(code: 0): No route found for \"HEAD /\" at /home/ubuntu/symfony_backend/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/EventListener/RouterListener.php:123, Symfony\\Component\\Routing\\Exception\\ResourceNotFoundException(code: 0):  at /home/ubuntu/symfony_backend/var/cache/prod/appProdProjectContainerUrlMatcher.php:1585)"} []
```

Well, I don't see or I don't understand relevant information about this.

But I'm investigating, and I see a [Syfony 3.3 Doctrine manual](https://symfony.com/doc/3.3/reference/configuration/doctrine.html) speaks about this issue and onther searchs show problems with MariaDB 10.2.7 and Up.

Well, I downgrade MariaDb to same version on original API:

Well, I've edited `app/config/config.yml` trying 5.6 a 5.2 (this is logical value return with `mysql -Version`

```
# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   pdo_mysql
        host:     "%database_host%"
        port:     "%database_port%"
        dbname:   "%database_name%"
        user:     "%database_user%"
        password: "%database_password%"
        server_version: 5.6
        charset:  UTF8
```

Shell

```
mysql -Version
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.0.35-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2
```

Credentials on config are correct and try differents version with port 3306, host to localhost...

```
parameters:
    database_host: 127.0.0.1
    database_port: null
    database_name: c1farid
    database_user: c1fariduser
    database_password: CorrectPassWorD
```

Answer (score 0):

More simple.

```
bin/console cache:clear --env=prod
// Clearing the cache for the prod environment with debug false


[OK] Cache for the "prod" environment (debug=false) was successfully cleared.
```

Not modify anything, and only I forget **stupid** message error from Exception Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException .